# Health Device Profile (HDP) support in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Does iOS supports HDP(Health Device Profile)? is there any examples available ?

Answer (score 2):

iOS does not support HDP for Bluetooth 2.1. It can connect to anything using Bluetooth 4.0 LE (CoreBluetooth), but you're essentially implementing the profile yourself by looking up services and characteristics.

Comment: Hi I am looking into this information and the article here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387 says its not been tracked by Apple anymore so i am confused if it suport HDP profile or not , or it can connect to any device that has BLE support ?

Comment: iOS does not have built-in support for any health profiles. You'd have to do something like in this example: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

No, not at this time. [HDP is not supported by iOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387).